# Java: Optimized way of reading file, validate that file line by line and then split and write that file into smaller files.?

Tags: java

I am trying to read  a file around 160 MB using Buffered Reader and then reading each line into string and validate(check first character in each line ). if the file is validated then i re- read file & split the files based on addresses in the line and save that in map as multiple lines can go to same address. once the complete file is read i write them through FTPS.String uses too much memory

File format
blocks of AJZ/AJJZ/AJJJZ
From A line we have to extract the address and then send that block(AJZ) , one block can be sent to multipl addresses and if more than one block belong to same address(eg Address2) we shud consolidate blocks

AAddress1,Address2
J7777
Z02

A00Address2,Address3
JH77
Z00...

Comment: Just don't read it into a `String` then? You're just checking the first character, so keep a `boolean` for whether it's validated on the first pass through. If the file is valid, then go through the file again and write to the smaller files one line at a time. It will be slower than loading it all into memory at once, but if you're running out of memory, then you don't really have another option.

Comment: Does `Files.lines(filename).filter(yourPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList())` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Flyweight design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to compress your string.

For example, you can store each word only once and use a placeholder (some integer) unique for each word in the original text. This way you end up with an array of placeholders.